# I would like to persist add in store without reducer. However, I am not sure how to setup my store accordingly with this

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
const store =  createStore(
    rootReducers, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

let persistor = persistStore(store);
export {store,persistor};
```

Comment: What do you mean "without reducer"? This will persist exactly nothing - you will have to wrap your reducer in `persistReducer` so something gets persisted.